# Parse iOS SDK - 'You have to call setApplicationId:clientKey: on Parse to configure Parse.'

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I like to think I'm pretty well versed in using the Parse SDK and have several apps successfully running with it. But I'm at a real loss and completely baffled by the following error I'm getting when trying to run a new app I'm making using the Parse SDK in iOS (Swift)

The error is as follows;

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'You have to call setApplicationId:clientKey: on Parse to configure Parse.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010da75f35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010f5b9bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010da75e6d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
3   CourierCo                           0x000000010c6c0ede +[Parse getApplicationId] + 53
4   CourierCo                           0x000000010c6a7f6b +[PFInternalUtils dataFilePath:] + 53
5   CourierCo                           0x000000010c676655 +[PFObject(Private) objectFromDataFile:] + 44
6   CourierCo                           0x000000010c6b1a4b +[PFUser(Private) userFromDataFileWithName:] + 542
7   CourierCo                           0x000000010c6b1ee7 +[PFUser currentUser] + 86
8   CourierCo                           0x000000010c63ce18 _TFC9CourierCo7Vehicle14parseClassNamefMS0_FT_GSQSS_ + 168
9   CourierCo                           0x000000010c63d310 _TToFC9CourierCo7Vehicle14parseClassNamefMS0_FT_GSQSS_ + 32
10  CourierCo                           0x000000010c67ae92 +[PFObject registerSubclass] + 31
11  CourierCo                           0x000000010c63cd43 _TFC9CourierCo7Vehicle4loadfMS0_FT_T_ + 67
12  CourierCo                           0x000000010c63cd69 _TToFC9CourierCo7Vehicle4loadfMS0_FT_T_ + 25
13  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010f5bb648 call_load_methods + 716
14  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010f5be147 load_images + 231
15  ???                                 0x000000010c8a2a81 0x0 + 4505348737
16  ???                                 0x000000010c8ad592 0x0 + 4505392530
17  ???                                 0x000000010c8ad42c 0x0 + 4505392172
18  ???                                 0x000000010c8ad69d 0x0 + 4505392797
19  ???                                 0x000000010c8a2d40 0x0 + 4505349440
20  ???                                 0x000000010c8a6074 0x0 + 4505362548
21  ???                                 0x000000010c8a227c 0x0 + 4505346684
22  ???                                 0x00007fff61b14163 0x0 + 140734832394595
23  ???                                 0x00007fff61b13277 0x0 + 140734832390775
24  ???                                 0x00007fff61b0f276 0x0 + 140734832374390
25  ???                                 0x00007fff61b0f036 0x0 + 140734832373814
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

The reason why I'm baffled is the fact that my app was working perfectly, and then all of a sudden (after not changing anything to do with Parse) I get this error every time I run it.

I'm calling `Parse.setApplicationId("app id", clientKey: "client key")` in `func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool` as you would expect but for some reason Parse isn't registering.

I've tried creating a new project, removing all calls to Parse (other than setting the application id and client key) but I still get the same error.

Has anyone seen this error before and successfully resolved it?

Any help appreciated.

**EDIT:
Answer found!***

It was to do with overriding the load() function in my custom PFObject class. Removing this load() function made it all work ok.

Comment: Do you make any calls to Parse that could occur before the code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` might be run?

Comment: I don't think so - I certainly haven't added anything in before setting the application ID and client key to make it stop working like it has.

Comment: Are you overriding the `load` method in any of your classes?